# Two apps take same icons in files

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ipad

I have installed UAT and preprod version of same app name. Infact these has unique bundle identifier and icon.

So the problem now is, inside files app, these two apps have separate folders with the same icon.

Why is it happens? any solution?

I need two apps with their corresponding icons.

Answer (score 0):

It only happens, if we are using same provisioning and bundle ids for both the apps. please check it. Also try by clearing derived data and cache before run.

Comment: I checked it. They have different provisioning and bundle id